# "cp: cannot stat" error while installing Java 9 on OpenSuse 42.3

Tags: opensuse, java-9

I am trying to install Java 9 on OpenSuse 42.3.
I have downloaded java 9 rpm file and trying to install on OpenSuse 42.3 but I get below error.

```
user@localhost:~> sudo rpm -ivh Downloads/jdk-9_linux-x64_bin.rpm 
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
   1:jdk-9-2000:9-ga                  ################################# [100%]
Unpacking JAR files...
    plugin.jar...
    javaws.jar...
    deploy.jar...
cp: cannot stat '/usr/java/jdk-9/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/sun-java.png': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/usr/java/jdk-9/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/sun-javaws.png': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/usr/java/jdk-9/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/sun-java.png': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/usr/java/jdk-9/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/sun-javaws.png': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/usr/java/jdk-9/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/sun-java.png': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/usr/java/jdk-9/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/sun-javaws.png': No such file or directory
update-alternatives: using /usr/java/jdk-9/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode
update-alternatives: error: alternative appletviewer can't be slave of javac: it is a slave of java
warning: %post(jdk-9-2000:9-ga.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 2
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Could this be  possibly be because of permissions denied to create a folder or failing to find relevant permissions to cp/scp? Also IMHO this should be moved to [unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: It is hard to believe that installation failed due to permission because I'm installing using `sudo`. could you please let me know how can I move this to unix.stackexchange?

Comment: You can create a question there and close this post that to move to unix.stackexchange.

Comment: Getting the same in RHEL 7.4

Answer (score 0):

I installed Java 9.0.4 on Centos7 and got only 'can not stat' messages but the installation seems to be OK:

```
sudo rpm -ivh jdk-9.0.4_linux-x64_bin.rpm
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
   1:jdk-9.0.4-2000:9.0.4-ga          ################################# [100%]
Unpacking JAR files...
    plugin.jar...
    javaws.jar...
    deploy.jar...
cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/java/jdk-9.0.4/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/sun-java.png’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/java/jdk-9.0.4/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/sun-javaws.png’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/java/jdk-9.0.4/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/sun-java.png’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/java/jdk-9.0.4/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/sun-javaws.png’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/java/jdk-9.0.4/lib/desktop/icons/HighContrast/16x16/apps/sun-java.png’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/java/jdk-9.0.4/lib/desktop/icons/HighContrast/16x16/apps/sun-javaws.png’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/java/jdk-9.0.4/lib/desktop/icons/HighContrast/48x48/apps/sun-java.png’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/java/jdk-9.0.4/lib/desktop/icons/HighContrast/48x48/apps/sun-javaws.png’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/java/jdk-9.0.4/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/sun-java.png’: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/java/jdk-9.0.4/lib/desktop/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/sun-javaws.png’: No such file or directory
:
```

The directory tree after installation looks like:

```
:tree /usr/java/jdk-9.0.4/lib/desktop/icons

/usr/java/jdk-9.0.4/lib/desktop/icons
├── hicolor
│   ├── 16x16
│   │   ├── apps
│   │   │   └── sun-jcontrol.png
│   │   └── mimetypes
│   │       ├── gnome-mime-application-x-java-archive.png
│   │       ├── gnome-mime-application-x-java-jnlp-file.png
│   │       └── gnome-mime-text-x-java.png
│   └── 48x48
│       ├── apps
│       │   └── sun-jcontrol.png
│       └── mimetypes
│           ├── gnome-mime-application-x-java-archive.png
│           ├── gnome-mime-application-x-java-jnlp-file.png
│           └── gnome-mime-text-x-java.png
├── HighContrast
...
```